# show username in html Spring Security

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-security

I have working Spring security configuration and now I want to show username on html page.
my method to get username:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody  public String currentUserName() {
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String name = user.getUsername();
        return name;
    }
}
```

so navigating http://localhost:8080/username shows me correct username

but when I try to show username on html(using GET request) nothing happens

here what I tried to do:

```
<head>
<script>
function httpGet()
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://localhost:8080/username", false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
   document.getElementById('usr').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
window.onload=httpGet;
</script>

</head>

<div id="usr">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: also you can change signature `currentUserName()` to `currentUserName(Principal principal)` and return `principal.getName();`

Comment: @zelenov try `xmlHttp.open( "GET", "/username", false )` without the context path

Comment: try adding an alert in the  javascript alert(xmlHttp.responseText);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById('usr').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/username", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Also consider using something like jQuery to do the request, it's way easier.
And you can debug the js code with Chrome dev tools for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still displays nothing

Comment: I would suggest to open the web page in chrome or firefox and open the dev tools. You could check if there is some error and even put a breakpoint inside the onreadystatechange function